# Pull list from SOAP web service

Tags: java, web-services, soap, soap-client

How to pull  array list  from server to client side in SOAP web service in Java?

Example :

**Server contains** : list of Books

**Client** :  *request* list of all books , in the *response* of *server*  list of books should return to client.

i ll get list of books in the response of server and then how to consume that list in client side ?

Comment: https://www.google.com/search?q=java+and+soap+tutorial

Comment: not useful..   they are simple tutorial not matching my requirement.

Comment: any one know answer ?

Comment: Then you may need to look at your question again.  It's broad, and doesn't inidcate what work you may have already tried.  Please check out the faq for tips on good questions.

Comment: Things to add to your question if you want it answered: Does your server already implement a web service, or are you trying to implement both?  If you're implementing both, have you tried a 5-minute `JAX-WS` tutorial (e.g. http://java.dzone.com/articles/jax-ws-hello-world)?  If you feel what you need is more complicated than this, how is it different?  What more are you trying to do?

Comment: Thanks for tutorial , yes i am implementing both .
In response of server i get the list , that list how to consume in client side ???

Comment: all tutorial contains simple String response instead of that i need List.

Answer (score 2):

In short:

The service:

```
package webservice;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import javax.jws.WebMethod;
import javax.jws.WebService;
@WebService
public class BookWebService {
List<Book> allBooks = new ArrayList<>();
@WebMethod
public List<Book> getAllBooks() {
return allBooks;
}
@WebMethod
public void addBook (Book book) {
this.allBooks.add(book);
}
}
```

The client:

```
package root;
import java.util.List;
import javax.xml.ws.WebServiceRef;
import webservice.Book;
import webservice.BookWebService;
import webservice.BookWebServiceService;
public class MainClient {
@WebServiceRef(wsdlLocation="http://localhost:8080/LibraryWs/BookWebServiceService?wsdl")
private static BookWebServiceService service;
public static void main(String[] args) {
MainClient cl = new MainClient();
cl.start();
}
public void start() {
service = new BookWebServiceService();
BookWebService port = service.getBookWebServicePort();
System.out.println("All books: "+port.getAllBooks());
Book book = new Book();
book.setTitle("Journey");
book.setPages(233);
port.addBook(book);
System.out.println("All books: "+port.getAllBooks());
}
}
```

The complete detailed steps are available here:
[JAX-WS Simple Client and Service](http://dev.vvirlan.com/jax-ws-simple-webservice-and-client/)

Comment: Your answer is correct to me but your link is broken.

Answer (score -1):

You cannot use List, because interface types are not allowed in webservice communication (both as return type of an action and in parameters).

You need to specify an list implementation instead, like ArrayList.

Also Book must not be interface, and all its fields must be of type that is not interface. You cannot pass ANY data that is of an interface type, anywhere.

Did you have any exceptions while trying to run / deploy your webservice ? If so, why didnt you mentioned about it ?

If you just dont know how to code it, why you just didnt tried use an List/ArrayList/WhateverList as regular type like String ?

Comment: "You cannot use List, because interface types are not allowed in webservice communication (both as return type of an action and in parameters)." That's not true.

Comment: ACV is right, you can use List. More precisely, you have to use types supported by JAXB (Jakarta XML Binding). For example, you can return a list of instances when those are entities, i.e instances of classes from your persistence unit. In the original poster's case, (s)he can return a list of books List<Book> if and only if Book is a class supported by JAXB, which is the case if this class was generated as an entity class from a SQL table and is listed in persistence.xml.